# tail -f <filename>, print line number as well

Tags: linux, logging, tail

Is there a way to modify so that the `tail -f` lists the line number of the current file as well.

Something similar to `grep -n <Strings> *`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This command takes into account the number of lines above also

```
tail -f -n +1 yourfile.txt | nl
```

Comment: This is better for my script

Answer (score 10):

## Try `less`

Instead of using `tail` to follow data and `less` or `nl` for numbering, I suggest using a single tool for both:

```
less -N +F <filename>
```

This will make `less` print line numbers *and* follow the file. From [`man less`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/less):

> F
>
> Scroll forward, and keep trying to read when the end of file is reached.  Normally this command would be used when  already  at the  end  of  the file.  It is a way to monitor the tail of a file which is growing while it is being viewed.  (The behavior is similar to the `tail -f` command.)

You could do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to stop following when inside `less`; to start following again, you could press <kbd>F</kbd> again. With this method, you get the additional goodies that `less` offers like regex-based search, tags, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `less` command,

```
tail -f <filename> | less -N
```

According to man page of `less`

> -N or --LINE-NUMBERS
>           Causes  a  line  number to be displayed at the beginning of each
>           line in the display.

Comment: `tail -f <filename> | grep -n` shows Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try `grep --help' for more information.

Comment: Ok, @VikasGoel try the first suggestion then.